# JPQL - if parameter is null, then all

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

Is there a possibility in JPQL to return all results and ignore the null value in parameter instead of looking for null values?

For example:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM PromoCode p " +
            "WHERE (LOWER(p.name) LIKE LOWER(concat('%', concat(:query, '%'))) OR " +
            "LOWER(p.promoCode) LIKE LOWER(concat('%', concat(:query, '%')))) AND p.type = :type")
Page<PromoCode> search(@Param("query") String query, @Param("type") PromoCode.Type type, Pageable pageable)
```

How do I ignore `:type`, if it's null?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you most likely need is a `CriteriaQuery` built in a custom repository. It is designed exactly for what you need, construction of a query dependent on various factors.

If you really want to stick with `@Query` you can always make that part optional this way:

```
AND (p.type = :type OR :type is null)
```

The problem starts to surface when there will be more params like that. Your query will be hard to maintain and understand.

Comment: Doesn't the code you wrote fetches the rows where type == null? If type is null, I need to fetch the rows that contain any value in type column

Comment: If the :type is present it fetches it.. if not.. it fetches all the rows